# Java compile on Ubuntu with openjdk, then run on windows with sun java gives error

Tags: netbeans, cross-compiling, java, ubuntu-12.04

I have been developing a Java program in Netbeans/Ubuntu 12.04 using OpenJdk. I have got this program to run successfully using the .jar in Linux, but when I copy the .jar to my Windows 7 virtual machine I get the following error;
"Could not find the main class: testprogram.Main. Program will exit."

Also this program uses no external libraries.

Comment: Are you sure you've placed the JAR in your classpath on Windows?  How are you (or Netbeans) invoking the JAR?

Comment: I believe netbeans does this automatically when I specify the main class, however if it does not then this is a possibility.

Comment: Have you specified a main class?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404001/could-not-find-the-main-class-program-will-exit

Comment: @RyanAmos I have just checked my project settings, my main class is set. That is the same error that I am receiving, but our issue is different as i am able to get it working in my IDE and with the .jar, but only in linux

Comment: If you move the *same* JAR from one OS to another, it behaves differently?

Edit: Maybe your file names aren't matching up? Windows ignores case while Unix is case sensitive. If you have `main` and `Main`, that would cause problems, or if you have `testprogram.Main` and `testProgram.Main`

Comment: @RyanAmos I changed the name of the Main class to Controller, and the error became "Could not find the main class: testprogram.Controller. Program will exit.". I have reverted to JDK 6, I no longer receive this error.

Comment: Then you have found your solution :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix to this problem was to use JDK 6 as opposed to JDK 7, still unsure as to why this error was produced, but this change has fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you compile in JDK 7 and then try to run it in Java 6?

Comment: @Bill I compiled in OpenJDK 7, and attempted to run it on a machine that has an up to date sun Java.

Answer (score 0):

How did you start your program? Did you use `java -jar yourjarfile.jar`?

Maybe your Manifest file does not defined applycation entry point. You can study this topic [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

Comment: The error is: "Could not find the main class: testprogram.Main. Program will exit." So, the Manifest *does* contain a `Main-Class` attribute.